# Smart cast to 'X' is impossible, because 'X' is a public API property declared in different module

Tags: kotlin

I have some code that looks like this

```
fun onMessage(message: Message) {
    message.property?.also {
        repository.updateProperty(message.property)
    }
}
```

where the parameter of `updateProperty()` is not nullable. The compiler gives an error:

`Smart cast to 'Property' is impossible, because 'Message' is a public API property declared in different module`

What is the best solution to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out it was as easy as using `it` instead.

```
fun onMessage(message: Message) {
    message.property?.also {
        repository.updateProperty(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here may be the reason why:

A smart cast is only valid when multiple accesses of the same property are guaranteed to return the same value. If the property being accessed is defined in a different module from the access location, the module containing the property can be recompiled separately from the module where it’s accessed, breaking the key requirement of the smart cast.

reference: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/what-is-the-reason-behind-smart-cast-being-impossible-to-perform-when-referenced-class-is-in-another-module/2201/2